# How to make the points and lines in the legend(ggplot) have different colors

Tags: r

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg)+
  geom_point(aes(x=displ,y=cty,color=drv))+
  geom_line(aes(x=displ,y=cty,color=drv))
```

Here are the results

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvJlH.png)

Now I want the points and lines in the legend to have different colors. Specifically, for example, for a classification with a drv of 4, the point color is red and the line color is green, and it is required to be displayed in the legend

**Please avoid using 'fill' aesthetics to fill the points and 'color' aesthetics to draw the lines**, because I will have requirements for the shape of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use package [`ggnewscale`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggnewscale/ggnewscale.pdf), function `new_scale_colour` to replace the existing, active scale with another one. See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73499310/controlling-ggplot2-legend-order-with-new-scale-color-of-ggnewscale) and [this R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/06/how-to-use-multiple-colour-scales-in-ggplot-with-ggnewscale/) .
Two notes:

- The line width is greater in order to make the points more visible;
- I have changed the order of lines and points layers so that the lines do not overplot the points.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)

clr_lines <- setNames(c("green", "cyan", "magenta"), c("4", "f", "r"))
clr_points <- setNames(c("red", "black", "yellow"), c("4", "f", "r"))

ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_line(aes(x = displ, y = cty, color = drv), linewidth = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = clr_lines) +
  # start a new scale
  new_scale_colour() +
  geom_point(aes(x = displ, y = cty, color = drv)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = clr_points)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>